# Cannot find resource StAccountsDomainModel.rlinq embedded in assembly. Telerik OpenAccess

Tags: asp.net, azure, tfsbuild, telerik-open-access

We have application hosted on azure cloud service platform using azure database. We have TFS hosted build controller which build application and deploy it on azure platform.

Application working fine on local but we are getting following error when we deploy on azure. I Google every possible ways but still getting error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/external-tools-howto-integrate-enhancer-msbuild.html) shows how to use OpenAccess ORM without installing.

Additional information regarding the deployment of an OpenAccess ORM model can be found [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/getting-started-root-quickstart-aspnet-deploy.html).